# Expected ')' to match '(' from instead saw while running the JSHint

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jshint

I am using the d3 library to draw a path/line, for this I need to use **stroke-dasharray** property as given below.

This works fine for me,

```
vis.append("path")
   .attr("class", "predictedLowerCI")
   .attr("d", valueline5(scope.rowdata))
   .attr({ 'stroke-dasharray': (2, 2) })
```

When I run JSHint, I get the following error

> "Expected ')' to match '(' from line 194 and instead saw ','."

where I have used **stroke-dasharray**. The error comes for this syntax `(2, 2)`, basically `JSHint` does not seem to like this syntax of d3. Is there way to tell JSHint this is a valid syntax?

Comment: Well, what is `(2, 2)` supposed to mean? Javascript doesn't have tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's looking for a string

```
vis.append('path')
   .attr('class', 'predictedLowerCI')
   .attr('d', valueline5(scope.rowdata))
   .attr({'stroke-dasharray': '2, 2'}) // change made here
```

Comment: Why keep the superfluous `()`?

Comment: nice spot @deceze, cheers ;)